# How best to deploy DokuWiki within my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokuwiki

I would like to install DokuWiki within my Rails application at domain.com/wiki

1. Would it be best to unzip and install it in public/wiki?
2. I don't want to have to commit/push/pull DokuWiki pages every time I'm working on my application. Would you suggest telling git to ignore the wiki directory entirely? or is there a better way to do this, such a ignoring the location of the flat files within the /wiki?

Ideally all changes I make to the actual wiki source code will have revision control but the authored wiki pages wouldn't.

Your thoughts and experiences would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, DokuWiki is a PHP Application. If you want to deploy your application on the same server, the most simple solution (but not the most efficient one) is to setup Apache with Passenger (mod_rails) and mod_php (or equivalent solution for PHP pages).

Then, configure the vhost for using passenger. Choose the folder where you want to deploy DokuWiki and [disable Passenger for it](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerenabled_lt_on_off_gt). The documentation shows a similar solution for a WordPress installation.

Finally, exclude the DokuWiki folder from version control.

If you use Capistrano, I also suggest you to deploy DokuWiki on a separate folder and use Capistrano to create a symlink each time you deploy a new version of your Rails application. In this way, you don't need to deal with the DokuWiki folder each time you deploy your Rails application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Rails so I can't give you an answer on 1.) but re 2.), I have found that it's enough to ignore the `/data` directory to prevent actual wiki contents from being committed.

Maybe commit the initial structure in `/data` (the status it has directly after a fresh installation) so you have an intact structure in your repository.

Comment: If I commit the initial structure of /data won't I get warnings for all future changes – "git diff" etc – or if I was to do "git commit -am" would it not include all /data changes automatically?

I can see how ignoring /data completely, would work however.